# .NET Database Migrations Tool

Tags: .net, database

I need some .NET tool which provide ability for working with database schema and data migrations.

For Example:
Two developers works in one project.

1. The first developer creates table ***User***
2. The second developer wants to use the first developer's database schema and adds other table ***Goods*** to it.
3. The first developer adds to the latest database version table ***Currency***
   ...

Each of them need to work with latest database version. They could make database backup each time, but this is bad solution. Maybe exists some tool which could help.

Please help me to resolve with problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for now answer is much more simpler than two years ago:

Use Entity Framework Migrations and be happy

Answer (score 2):

Red-Gate makes [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) which may provide the functionality that you need.

Otherwise you could use [Schema Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio if you have Premium or Ultimate and somehow automate the differences.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good solution that works like the Entity Framework migrations. https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Migration